# Datatables creados dinamicamente con Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar....

Hoy recurro a ustedes para explicarles mi problema y espero me puedan dar alguna luz por que honestamente no la consigo.

Yo estoy creando un Datatable de manera dinámica, cabe mencionar que estoy usando PHP (Laravel), por una necesidad muy puntual estoy mostrando el Datatable en un Modal.

El asunto es que estoy haciendo uso del Plugin Datables https://datatables.net ya que quiero usar la opcion nativa de Buscar.

El Databale no lo creo con PHP, lo creo usando AJAX, les muestro como lo estoy haciendo:

```
$.ajax
({
   url:'../../ingresoarticulos/buscarIngresosTerminadosDesechados',
   type:'get',
   dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
        $cargando.show();

    },
    complete: function () {
        $cargando.hide();

    },
   success: function (data)
   {
        var $resultado=data.ingresosTerminadosDesechados;
        var $filas='';

       if($.isEmptyObject($resultado))
       {
           $filas += "<tr>";
           $filas += "<td colspan='7'><h4 style='text-align: center'>"+$txt_finished_discarded_items+"</h4></td>";
           $filas += "</tr>";
       }
        $.each($resultado,function (index,valor)
        {
           var $id = "<td id='id'>"+valor.id+"</td>";
           var $numeroSolicitud = "<td id='solicitud_id' >"+valor.id_solicitud+"</td>";
           var $numeroSerie = "<td id='numero_serie'>"+valor.serie_articulo+"</td>";
           var $numeroSku = "<td id='numero_sku'>"+valor.sku_articulo+"</td>";
           var $totalServicio = "<td id='total_servicio'>"+parseFloat(valor.total_ingreso).toFixed(2)+"</td>";
           var $agregarServicio="<td class='click'><input type='button' id='agregar_servicio' class='btn-sm btn-info col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 incluir' value="+$txt_btn_add+"></td>";
           if(valor.estatus_ingreso==="Terminado")
           {
               var $estadoArticulo = "<td id='estado_articulo'  style='color: #3d8b3d;font-weight: bold'>"+$txt_status_article_finished+"</td>";
               var $pesoArticulo = "<td id='peso_articulo'>"+parseFloat(valor.peso_articulo).toFixed(2)+"</td>";
           }
           else
               if(valor.estatus_ingreso==="Desechado")
               {
                   var $estadoArticulo = "<td id='estado_articulo' style='color: #b0141a;font-weight: bold'>"+$txt_status_article_discarded+"</td>";
                   var $pesoArticulo = "<td id='peso_articulo'>"+parseFloat(0.00).toFixed(2)+"</td>";
               }


           $filas += "<tr data-status='"+valor.estatus_ingreso+"'>";
            $filas += $id;
            $filas += $numeroSolicitud;
            $filas += $numeroSerie;
            $filas += $numeroSku;
            $filas += $pesoArticulo;
            $filas += $totalServicio;
            $filas += $estadoArticulo;
            $filas += $agregarServicio;
           $filas += "</tr>";
        });
       $("#tablemodalarticulostd tbody").html($filas);
```

Todo alli funciona perfecto, el problema se presenta cuando le paso el pluging de DataTable.

```
$solicitudEnvio.DataTable({
            // "paging": false,
            // "info": false,
            //
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "language": {
                "search": "Buscar: ",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Escriba los datos que desea buscar",
                "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sUrl": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                }
            }

        });
```

La ventana muestra las caracteristicas propias del pluging pero no hace el funcionamiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo se? pues... no filtra, no cuenta lo registros y no muestra la paginacion, he leido mucho acerca del caso, pero la verdad no he consegudo la manera de que funcione.

Espero me puedan dar alguna idea de que hacer. Gracias.

Comment: ok recuerda lo siguiente, la inicialización de la tabla `$('#myTable').DataTable();` debe hacerse una vez se ha completado la carga de datos a esta y debes destruirla una vez cierres el modal, en cuanto a la paginación solo se activa si sobrepasas la cantidad de registros mínimos de la tabla que creo son 5 o 10

Comment: Hola Carlos Gracias por responder, sabes que ya habia hecho eso, de ponerlo a cargar despues y el efecto es el mismo. Lo de la paginacion tienes razon solo que, cuando existe un registro al menos te marca la pagina 1, aqui no lo hace, ya antes he trabajado con los datatables pero usando solo PHP no Jquery y funciona perfecto.